# How to show a tooltip after clicking an SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an SVG circle, it has a small svg circle inside it and a polygon inside the small circle, when i click on the polygon it should rotate and it's working fine, but after rotation a tool-tip should appear above the polygon and i don't know how to show it, i put it in a div above my svg, here is my code:

```js
   document.querySelector('polygon').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('rotated');
});
```

```css
   .rotated {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
polygon {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="marker marker-index-0" style="display: none;">
   <h3>I should be a tooltip</h3>
  </div>
<svg>
<circle cx="40" cy="122.5" r="26" fill="red"></circle>
<g class="markerG" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,40,122.5)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" r="14" fill="#000000" style="cursor: pointer;"></circle><polygon points="1 -1 1 -7 -1 -7 -1 -1 -7 -1 -7 1 -1 1 -1 7 1 7 1 1 7 1 7 -1" fill="#ffffff"></polygon></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: To clarify, you don't have any code relating to the tooltip -- is this more of a question of what's the best way to hide and show a tooltip?

Comment: yes, thats the point of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transition alone won't do it, because you can't do anything after it's done.

Instead, it would be a good time for you to learn CSS Animations.

Note that I applied the classes to a container involving both the polygon and the tooltip, in order to avoid synchronization errors.

```js
document.querySelector('polygon').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(!document.getElementById('animationContainer').classList.contains("animated")) {
    document.getElementById('animationContainer').classList.add("animated");
 document.getElementById('animationContainer').classList.add("rotated");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('animationContainer').classList.toggle('rotated');
    document.getElementById('animationContainer').classList.toggle('faded');
  }
});
```

```css
@keyframes polygonAnimation {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
50% { transform: rotate(-90deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(-90deg); }
}
@keyframes polygonReverseAnimation {
0% { transform: rotate(-90deg); }
50% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
@keyframes markerAnimation {
0% { display: none; opacity: 0; }
50% { display: block; opacity: 0; }
100% { display: block; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes markerReverseAnimation {
0% { display: block; opacity: 1; }
50% { display: block; opacity: 0; }
100% { display: none; opacity: 0; }
}
#animationContainer .marker {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
.rotated polygon {
  animation-name: polygonAnimation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.rotated .marker {
  animation-name: markerAnimation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.faded polygon {
  animation-name: polygonReverseAnimation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.faded .marker {
  animation-name: markerReverseAnimation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="animationContainer">
<div class="marker marker-index-0">
   <h3>I should be a tooltip</h3>
</div>
<svg>
<circle cx="40" cy="122.5" r="26" fill="red"></circle>
<g class="markerG" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,40,122.5)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" r="14" fill="#000000" style="cursor: pointer;"></circle><polygon points="1 -1 1 -7 -1 -7 -1 -1 -7 -1 -7 1 -1 1 -1 7 1 7 1 1 7 1 7 -1" fill="#ffffff"></polygon></g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you never specified to show the tool-tip ;)

```js
document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('polygon').classList.toggle('rotated');
  document.getElementById('marker').classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
.rotated {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
polygon {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="marker marker-index-0" id="marker" style="display: none;">
   <h3>I should be a tooltip</h3>
  </div>
<svg>
<circle cx="40" cy="122.5" r="26" fill="red"></circle>
<g class="markerG" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,40,122.5)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" r="14" fill="#000000" style="cursor: pointer;"></circle><polygon points="1 -1 1 -7 -1 -7 -1 -1 -7 -1 -7 1 -1 1 -1 7 1 7 1 1 7 1 7 -1" fill="#ffffff"></polygon></g>
</svg>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did, thank you, but i want to show it on rotate then remove it again when the polygon goes back to normal, can i do that?

Comment: There, edited :) I simply created a class called show and toggled it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to your event listener that rotates the svg. The rest is just css.

```
$('.marker-index-0').show();
```

Btw you have cursor pointer on the inner circle, but it only works on clicking the polygon. That's not intuitive design.